# Stuck with git push

Tags: git, github

Decided to understand working of version control today but not successful.
I Created a repository in github then I used the following commands:

1. Changed directory to a local folder I want to sync with.
2. Initialize Git repository with `git init`
3. Git status did not show error and showed my file
   .4 Then I made some changes to a file and added and committed it within terminal.
4. Then `git remote add origin` URL of GitHub repo
5. And after writing git push origin `master` I am asked to type in my Username and Password and I get the following:

   ```
   Password for 'https://Kozik1@github.com': 
   To https://github.com/Kozik1/dsdadd.git
    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Kozik1/dsdadd.git'
   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
   MacBook-Air-Nadezda:vre nadezdakosinova
   ```

Comment: Do not run `git init`. Clone the github repository and then make your changes. After that commit and push normally. It will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a pull first like this:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Then try to push. That should fix it.

Comment: That did the trick for me! 10x a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you have created a GitHub repo first, it is likely to include a small `README.md`, or a `LICENSE.txt`.
Meaning its history might not be empty.

In that case, it is best to:

- clone it first (that will set the remote `origin` for you, and the local `master` branch will already track `origin/master`)
- copy over your files in it
- add, commit and push

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull master branch before pushed your changes over there.

```
git status
```

This command will show you the status of your local repository, whether it's up to date or behind from the master or ahead of the master.

It's always suggested to pull from master before pushed your changes there.

1. Pull from master

   ```
   git pull origin master
   ```
2. add all your changes to git

   ```
   git add --all
   ```
3. Commit your changes

   ```
   git commit -m "Message"
   ```
4. Push your changes to git

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is GitHub *already initialized* the git repo for you. Maybe you selected the option **Initialize this repository with a README**. The way forward is:-

1. Clone the GitHub repo: `git clone <repo-url>`.
2. Make changes.
3. Commit and push as usual.

Do not:-

1. Initialize the repo again with `git init`.
2. No need to add remote URL. It is already added as part of the cloning process. Check the available remotes with `git remote -v`.

**Alternative: Use with Caution!**

If you are sure there is nothing useful in the GitHub repo (i.e. if you have nothing except the GitHub created template README file), you can **overwrite** the repo on GitHub with your changes. You will lose the README file.

```
git push origin master --force
```